# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. " i tried my best but i could not resolve it.."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm getting this error after I update my android studio...

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-full.properties'

My  "app Build.gradle"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.newsaggregator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    implementation('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    implementation project(':library')
}
```

My "project build.gradle"

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

My "library Build.Gradle"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Can anyone help me figuring out what's causing this error?
Any ideas on how to get this working? if you need more information please let me know. I am very new to this. Thank you so much in advance.